# python snapshot program error

Tags: python, message, screenshot

Im running this program to take a snapshot of my screen and save it but getting an error message

```
import os
import sys
import time
import Image
import ImageGrab

SaveDirectory=r'C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Pictures'
ImageEditorPath=r'C:\WINDOWS\system32\mspaint.exe'
img=ImageGrab.grab()
saveas=os.path.join(SaveDirectory,'ScreenShot_'+time.strftime('%Y_%m_%d%_%H_%M_%S')+'.png')
img.save(saveas)
editorstring='""%s" "%s"'% (ImageEditorPath,saveas) 
os.system(editorstring)
```

this is the Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/butt", line 10, in <module>
    saveas=os.path.join(SaveDirectory,'ScreenShot_'+time.strftime('%Y_%m_%d%_%H_%M_%S')+'.png')
ValueError: Invalid format string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the `%_` in your format string for `strftime` - it's not a valid value.  Replace the format string with the following and you should be fine:

`'%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S'`

You can tell the format string is at fault because the error raised (`ValueError: Invalid format string`) refers to a format string, and the only format string in line 10 is this one.  You can check the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html) to see what characters would be valid entities.  `%_` is not one of them, and I'm guessing that it was just a typographical error.

Answer (score 1):

There's something missing about the time:

```
str_time = time.strftime(your_real_date,'%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')
saveas=os.path.join(SaveDirectory,'ScreenShot_'+ str_time +'.png')
```

And each time, a little checking at Python Docs: [8.1.7. strftime() and strptime() Behavior](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) to ensure the use of any string/date convertion